# Settings to copy paste with correct indentation in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I copy and paste a piece of code using Visual Studio Code, **after pressing enter to create a new line**, the following happens:

[image]

It seems to keep the indentation created by the new line, adding the previous information from the copied snippet on top of it. I'd rather the code was auto-beautified on paste.

Can this behavior be changed through settings?

EDIT: I'm not referring to cross-platform copy-pasting, I'm referring to copying and pasting within the same file in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: a) do not copy the spaces of the first row from your source or b) when pasting it make sure your cursor is at the beginning of the line. Basically VSC just pasts it in there "as it is".

Comment: So is there no way to change that through settings?

Comment: Highlighting the text and moving it with `ALT + Arrowkey` will preserve indentation. For those looking for an alternative to changing settings.

Comment: Changing the `Auto Indent` setting from "Full" to "Advanced" worked for me!

Comment: For anyone wanting to see what this looks like, go do `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `V` in Sublime Text. It does this correctly.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

This is already integrated in vscode with `"editor.formatOnPaste": true` property in settings.

Comment: This unfortunately also formats any pasted code, which is not always what you want.

Comment: No, it is not the same. There is a long-living issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6392, which is closed, but actually not resolved, see comments. Everything we want is just to keep/match indentation level of the destination/target line, not the initial level, where text was copied from, while `"editor.formatOnPaste": true` is doing format, e.g. PEP8 fro python.

Comment: This is very opiniated and adds other undesirable modifications (or "beautifications") to the code.

Comment: Every Text Editor except VSCode allows a User to triple click and highlight any text.
CTRL C to copy and then CTRL V, CTRL V to duplicate the copied text.
Except in VS Code a triple Click CTRL C CTRL V adjusts the text and then the 2nd CTRL V makes it even worse.
CTRL C CTRL V is the most common of keyboard shortcuts, even my Mum knows this one.

Comment: This is not opinionated, as much as I agree with the rest of your statement. COPY and PASTE SHOULD HAVE NO opinion, it is COPY and PASTE they should only work 1 way.

Comment: No, this does not work for Python at the very least (indentation has meaning)

Comment: Setting it to 'false' (deactiving it) finally resolves this annoying default behaviour.

Comment: This also doesn't work if the formatter doesn't support formatting pasted sections.

Comment: It's not exactly the answer for the question, it will format everything instead of just keeping the correct indentation on for the paste, also will require python package that will perform formatting.

Comment: This doesn't work at all in Python. 1) Often the incorrect indentation on paste results in a syntax error, preventing the formatter from understanding the code in order to format it.  2) Even in cases where it doesn't introduce _syntax_ errors, it has the potential to introduce _logic_ errors, because it is impossible to automatically fix indentation in a language where indentation affects the program's meaning.

Comment: Try pasting after doing some indents on a new line. Only the first line of the pasted text is going to be properly indented. The rest of the code will just ignore your initial cursor position.

Answer (score 60):

This plugin may help you:

[paste-and-indent extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Rubymaniac.vscode-paste-and-indent)

You just have to change the shortcut and it works. Remember that you probably want to use `'cmd'` instead of `'ctrl'` if you're on a mac.
Like this:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+v",
    "command": "pasteAndIndent.action",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+v",
    "command": "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
    "when": "!editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+v",
    "command": "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

Comment: Use this to recreate Sublime Text 3 behaviour ie. cmd+shift+v to paste-indent: 
`{
    "key": "cmd+shift+v",
    "command": "pasteAndIndent.action",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}`

Comment: This solution still works. No more nasty extra tab vs code likes to put in every time I copy/paste .

Comment: Found it, go into "Keyboard Shortcuts" and then click the "Open Keyboard Shortcuts JSON" icon in the top right of the screen, hard to find I think!

Comment: This extension has a **big** downside: it formats the entire file code when pasting, not only the piece being pasted! I had to uninstall.

Comment: To locate the `keybindings.json` where you need to add the JSON snippet: Search for "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON) in Command Palette

Comment: You might also want to try this [one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gazugafan.vscode-indent-on-paste). Requires no setup, just install. Inspired by the extension mentioned above, but removes some other auto-formatting issues.

Comment: This extension is no longer working for me, any alternatives?

Comment: @JuanJoséRamírez Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67386577/873282, which recommends [paste-indent](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LesGrieve.paste-indent), which is a (maintained) fork of paste-and-indent.

Answer (score 44):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> seems to work out of the box.

Comment: This surprisingly works. Kinda annoying to have to do that, but it's better than nothing

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac

Comment: Did you try Cmd+V and Cmd+Z ?

Comment: leave it so a Microsoft product to fail to handle ability to copy and paste ... OMG  so happy I use a linux laptop ... thanks this workaround works

Comment: Amazing :D thankssss

Comment: For me the ctrl+z just undoes the paste (as expected, actually)

Comment: Haven't used Vscode in 3 years. Did you do ctrl+V first?

Answer (score 9):

This has been driving me mad, actually I needed to set `"editor.formatOnPaste": false`

Answer (score 5):

Give my [paste-indent](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LesGrieve.paste-indent) extension a try. Content is pasted according to the indentation of the current line and left justified to that indentation.

Comment: Thanks - this works out of the box for YAMLs!

Comment: This works, and better than the others, too. Well done, Sir! :-)

Comment: This extension works very well! Thanks for sharing. To make the pasting experience more streamlined, can add the following settings to keybindng.json: {
    "key": "cmd+v",
    "command": "extension.paste-indent",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  },

Comment: This solved it for me. Small suggestion: Give an example of what to add to keybindings.json exactly, like g3rry does.  It was a bit of figuring out for me to get it right. For now, for anyone looking for it, the command to bind is extension.paste-indent

Comment: Here is my setting added to keybindings.json:     {   "key": "shift+cmd+v",
        "command": "extension.paste-indent",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    }   One can also call out Command Palette then search paste-indent. Click the gear icon to set a hotkey via GUI

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `vs code 1.68.0` on `ubuntu 20.04` and the following works for me.

`ctrl`+`[`+`V`.

But then again, its just combination of `ctrl`+`[` and `ctrl`+`v` (if the normal `ctrl`+`v` is "right" running).
Likewise, if the normal `ctrl`+`v` is "left" running then, `ctrl`+`]`+`V`  can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Press `Shift + Alt + F` in the editor on Windows/Linux machine

Answer (score -7):

A simple fix is to try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> after copying the code. It will paste all codes correctly with indentations in it.

Comment: This does not work, exactly the same.
You try this: highlight paragraph - CTRL C, CTRL+SHFT+V, CTRL+SHFT+V.
It gets ugly!!!!

Comment: "To try" sounds strange. What exactly does that do? What if a user changed the shortcuts?

Comment: This will only work in sublime Text