# Incorrect indent in vs code when I paste codes?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here are my original html codes:

```
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="box box-1"></div>
<div class="box box-2"></div>
<div class="box box-3"></div>
```

and I just want to move the three div.box to div.container, but when I paste directly, it will be like this, just the fist line has correct indent:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box-1"></div>
<div class="box box-2"></div>
<div class="box box-3"></div>
</div>
```

I followed the instruction to disable the aotoIndent in the settings, but didn't work, so how to handle it?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790069/settings-to-copy-paste-with-correct-indentation-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Settings to copy paste with correct indentation in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790069/settings-to-copy-paste-with-correct-indentation-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 9):

If you cannot set the `editor.formatOnPaste` to `true`. Then use the following key combination to manually format/ indent `Alt+Shift+F`

Comment: Just to clarify. In settings you look under "DEFAULT USER SETTINGS" for `editor.formatOnPaste`. If it is set to `false`, copy the whole thing over to "USER SETTINGS" and put `true` instead.
**But be aware it will affect all code you paste in to the editor.**

Answer (score 2):

I know you said this didnt worked for you, but it did work for me and it may help others i think it worth mentioning:
This worked for me: Go to VS Code Settings -> from the User Settings tab -> Text Editor -> Formatting -> Untick the first option 'Format On Paste'

Answer (score 0):

Since your settings aren't working as desired, one good way to handle this behavior is to highlight the text and press `tab`. This will increase indentation on all lines. You can repeat to get to your desired indentation level.